# Is there a way to use formControlName or ngModel depends on input?

Tags: angular, angular9

I'm taking formControlName as input().Is there a way to use if controlName doesn't send as input,then use ngModel? Like a switch i want to use controlName or ngModel not both of them at the same time?

Comment: Something like an *ngIf ? One to display ngModel and one to display controlName? You could use a variable inside your component to determine which one to display

Comment: In this case, I suggested make a custom formComponent, not use `@Input`

Comment: @JeremyLucas this is the idea comes to my mind  in the first place but i don't want to apply that i'm looking for something like nz-input (ng zorro component) you can send controlName and also you can use  ngModel depends on which one you decide to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, I used `controlValueAccessor` to achieve this.